# Cookie blocked popup in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies

I have a website hosted in a server named msa_inst_server. In my login page, after user enter the username, I will check whether cookies are available or not, but when I access the login page in IE 6.0 in one machine in the local network, I am getting a pop up saying that

[alt text](http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/4288/cookieerrorinie.jpg)

I have added the  site to trusted zone, changed the settings to allow all cookies. But no way to get rid of this problem. Does the underscore in the server name matter?

Comment: IE doesn't allow setting of cookies on servernames containing underscores, although that shouldn't impact just one server.

Are any sites listed in IE's tools/internet options/security/restricted Sites list?

Comment: This isn't a StackOverflow question, having nothing to do with software development.  This might possibly be a ServerFault question, but I think it's probably better in SuperUser.

Comment: Unfortunately the image on the external image host has died, and I am not sure the question is now understandable. I will see if it can be put on hold for now, at least until it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any specific suggestions at this time, but the first place to start is download and install [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and use it to monitor the request/response to first determine whether the cookie is transferring between the server and Internet Explorer correctly.

As well, you may want to go to *Tools* > *Internet Options...* > *Privacy* tab and verify that *Sites...* does not have your site **Blocked**. You may also want to consider temporarily setting the level to **Accept All Cookies** and see if that makes a difference.